# How to display all documents with a unique key value and additional filtering in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I already found similar questions, but they did not give me a complete answer to my question. I have a collection containing statistics. I want to get all documents that match the given condition:

Documents with the most recent date possible, with a unique value for the `Location` field, but at the same time, so that the value of the `Continent` field is not empty.

A small slice of the collection structure:

```
{
  "_id": "2107649540296976100",
  "ISO code": "AFG",
  "Continent": "Asia",
  "Location": "Afghanistan",
  "Date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1582502400000"
    }
  },
  "hash_row": "8724109400677669585"
}


{
  "_id": "4570385068321604576",
  "ISO code": "OWID_AFR",
  "Continent": {
    "$numberDouble": "NaN"
  },
  "Location": "Africa",
  "Date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1581552000000"
    }
  "hash_row": "9823528570374963499"
}
```

I know that it is possible to get unique values with `distinct`, but this command displays me only the values of the location key, but not all documents in their entirety:

`test = parameters.collection.find({'Continent': {'$ne': np.NaN}}, sort=[('Date', -1)]).distinct("Location")` - return only list unique value key `Location`.

I tried to write this using aggregation as mentioned in other questions, but I don't quite understand how to include the part `query` here.

```
test = parameters.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {'$group': {'_id': '$Location'}},
        {'$sort': {'Date': -1}},
    ]
)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(test))
st.dataframe(df)
```

The output I get also only consists of a list of unique values, not documents.

[image]

How to correctly compose a query using Pymongo?

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question was specific, but here's how I was able to solve it in the end:

```
aggr = [
    {'$match': {'Continent': {'$ne': np.NaN}},
    {'$sort': {'Date': -1}},
    {'$group': {'_id': {'location': '$Location'}, 'doc': {"$first": "$$ROOT"}}},
    {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$doc"}}
]

df = parameters.collection.aggregate(aggr, allowDiskUse=True)
```